# CORS GET Request having issues with data length

Tags: apache, cordova, http, ionic-framework, cross-domain

I am creating an IonicFranmework based application.

For my APIs I have to enable `CORS` which is generally working perfectly. But in an API request where data character length is around 9000 doesn't return data. When I access that API directly in browser it works but with `Origin` header in request it doesn't return anything.

Any idea?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “doesn't return data”?

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov when I make this request via Postman it receives empty response, but when I open this URL directly in a browser it works perfectly. So its obvious its related to CORS requests.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the issue with the length of the data. You are not able to get the response because before the data is transferred to the server the API call is getting timed out. Please increase the time out of the http request and check it.

Comment: no, to be precise its 8000 char length. I hard coded generated string of 8000 it works but 8001 doesn't.